# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/CoreNFC.framework/CoreNFC, iOS11 and Xcode 9 beta

Tags: iphone, swift, ios11, xcode9-beta, core-nfc

I get this error and app get crash while run `CoreNFC sample` code in **Xcode 9.0 beta 2**

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/CoreNFC.framework/CoreNFC
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/2837709C-C852-4811-B696-38F2725554D4/iOS-11-by-Examples.app/iOS-11-by-Examples
  Reason: image not found
```

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Are you running on a device or in the simulator? CoreNFC might not be available in the simulator…

Comment: @MatusalemMarques I'm running in iOS 11 beta upgraded iPad mini.

Comment: here is how to mark Core NFC as Optional https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52562639/xcode-10-swift-4-app-with-corenfc-crashes-in-review-on-ios-12

Answer (score 13):

I combined some answers together to fix this thanks to @Chinchan Zu's comment

> here is how to mark Core NFC as Optional [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52562639/xcode-10-swift-4-app-with-corenfc-crashes-in-review-on-ios-12)

First you make import to NFCCore in "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" as optional as in this screenshot 
[image: linking nfcCore as optional]

Then inside your code you wrap your code with this #if check. Here is the class I used

```
#if canImport(CoreNFC)

import Foundation
import CoreNFC

#endif

class NFCManagar: NSObject {
  #if canImport(CoreNFC)
  var session: NFCNDEFReaderSession?
  #endif

  var items = [Item]()
  var completion: ((_ success: Bool, _ error: Error?)-> Void)?

  func beginScanning(items: [Item], completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool, _ error: Error?)-> Void) {
      self.completion = completion
      self.items.removeAll()
      self.items.append(contentsOf: items)

      #if canImport(CoreNFC)
      session = NFCNDEFReaderSession(delegate: self, queue: nil, invalidateAfterFirstRead: true)
      session?.alertMessage = "Hold your iPhone near check in/out device."
      session?.begin()
      #endif
  }

}

#if canImport(CoreNFC)
extension NFCManagar: NFCNDEFReaderSessionDelegate {

  // MARK: - NFCNDEFReaderSessionDelegate

  /// - Tag: processingTagData
  func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didDetectNDEFs messages: [NFCNDEFMessage]) {
          debugPrint("Nfc is detected")
  }

  /// - Tag: endScanning
  func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didInvalidateWithError error: Error) {
      // Check the invalidation reason from the returned error.
      if let readerError = error as? NFCReaderError {
          // Show an alert when the invalidation reason is not because of a success read
          // during a single tag read mode, or user canceled a multi-tag read mode session
          // from the UI or programmatically using the invalidate method call.
          if (readerError.code != .readerSessionInvalidationErrorFirstNDEFTagRead)
              && (readerError.code != .readerSessionInvalidationErrorUserCanceled) {

              debugPrint("Nfc didInvalidateWithError \(error)")
          }
      }

      // A new session instance is required to read new tags.
      self.session = nil
  }
}
#endif
```

Comment: not working with cocoapods, please look at our issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55077857/if-canimport-does-not-find-frameworks-with-cocoapods

Comment: I could not know why it does not work with Cocoapods. Could you post an issue on Cocoapods' repository on Github?

Comment: I have posted, still working on it... Should I specify weak_frameworks in other linker flags inside of build settings? maybe this cause issue? Because, I have specified in the past

Comment: I am sorry I have no clue

Answer (score 1):

CoreNFC is only available on iPhone 7 and iPhone 7 Plus devices. Make sure you're running your code on one of those.

See the WWDC session and the relevant documentation for more information.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/718/

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll check iPhone 7 with iOS 11 and will reply here.

Comment: I get an error in Xcode when I try to build on my iPhone 5s, it's related to NFC capabilities. But it works fine on my iPhone 7.

Answer (score 0):

For Xcode 11 make CoreNFC.framework "Do not Embed". And also wrap your code with #if check.